# How to tranfer one .txt to another using fopen with ("r" and "w") and replace " " with "\n"

Tags: c, string, file

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
void foo(const char *file1, char *file2)
{
   FILE *file = fopen(file1, "r");
   FILE *file0 = fopen (file2, "w");
   char nr = '\n';
   int c;

   fclose(file);
   fclose (file0);
}
int main(){
    const char t1[]="test.txt";
    const char t2[]="test1.txt";
    foo(t1,t2);
    return 0;

}
```

how to read the first file and copy to new file while replacing separators with newlines?

Comment: Read the file line by line with `fgets()` or reading chunks with `fread`. Before writing data back, cycle in the received buffer using `strcspn()` using its return value either to substitute the space eith the newline or detecting the end of the buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void foo(const char *file1, const char *file2) {
   FILE *fp1;
   FILE *fp2;

   int c;
   fp1 = fopen(file1,"r");
   fp2 = fopen(file2,"w+");
   while(1) {
      c = fgetc(fp1);
      if(feof(fp1)) {
         break;
      }
      if(c == ' ')
        c='\n';
      fprintf(fp2, "%c", c);
   }

   fclose(fp1);
   fclose(fp2);
}


int main(){
    const char t1[]="test.txt";
    const char t2[]="test1.txt";
    foo(&(t1[0]),&(t2[0]));
    return 0;

}
```

This shoud work

Comment: Why not use `fputc()` instead of `fprintf()`?